# Cannot access controls like Textboxes, Labels via threads in ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I am currently developing an ASP.NET application. I need to access certain controls like labels or textboxes through a non-UI thread, I am not able to do so. Could someone point me in the right direction? Even `Response.Write` doesn't seem to work.
By non-UI Thred, I mean a worker thread since loading of the UI is usually done by the main thread. I need my worker threads to be able to access controls like labels or textboxes to change their .text properties.

Comment: Please, share the code..

Comment: Why are you trying to access WinForm controls from an ASP.NET application?

Comment: I need to write some text to my textbox through a method which is executing on a separate worker threads  : I have tried the this TextBox2.Text = "ABC";   HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("ABC"); But nothing is written onto the textbox in the webpage

Comment: What do mean by "non UI thread" in a HTTP (web) application?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "not able to do so" do you get an exception ?Do you get an expected result?

Comment: It doesn't throw any exception but the result is not visible.

Comment: I have thread which has to display some text inside the text box every 5 seconds.

Comment: Please post relevant code sections. If there are any exception or errors, please add them also.

Comment: you need to first look at the asp.net page life cycle .https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: How do you create the 'non-UI thread'?

Comment: >>"I have thread which has to display some text inside the text box every 5 seconds".

It certainly won't work. if a browser received page response, any changes on the server side won't appear on the client until a page sends the next request tot he server. What scenario do you implement?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alternativly, you can use the `BackgroundWorker` class to execute some task in background.

BackgroundWorker will give an event `ProgressChanged`, use this ecent to write/update controls value on UI thread.